# Check if item of List<T> is valid

Tags: c#, typescript

I am porting a small program of mine from Typescript to C#. In the original program I had a lot of checks like this:

```
var array: T[] = [];
if (!array[1234]) { // do something }
```

which basically checks if 1234 is a wrong index (undefined) or if the item has been specifically set to `null` or `false` by me.

Now when porting this to C# I'm basically replacing `T[]` with `List<T>` but I don't know what is the quickest way to perform this check, since if I use an invalid index I get an exception.

So my question is, what is the best way to check for both invalid index and index of a `null` or `false` item?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check if the requested index is within the bounds you need to check `myIndex < myList.Count`.

If `T` is `bool`, you can do `!myList[ix]` like you are already doing.

In .NET, since `bool` is not nullable, you do not need to check if it is null. However, if `T` is nullable or a `Nullable<T>` i.e. `bool?`, you still need to do the `== null` check and also check if it isn't `false`.

If you are working in .NET 3.5 or above, you can write an extension method to make this a little easier on you. Here is something I whipped up to handle almost all cases (maybe all?).

```
public static class ListExtensions
{
   public static bool ElementIsDefined<T>(this List<T> list, int index)
   {
       if (index < 0 || index >= list.Count)
           return false;

       var element = list[index];
       var type = typeof (T);
       if (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type) != null)
       {
           if (element is bool?)
               return (element as bool?).Value;
           return element != null;
       }

       var defaultValue = default(T);
       // Use default(T) to actually get a value to check against.
       // Using the below line to create the default when T is "object" 
       // causes a false positive to be returned.
       return !EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(element, defaultValue);
   }
}
```

Quick overview of what this does:

- Checks if the index is within the bounds.
- Checks if the `Type` is `Nullable` (bool?, int?, etc.)
- If it is, then we have to double check if the type is `bool?` so we can correctly determine if `false` was supplied and return based on that.
- Then determines if the actual value out of the array is the default value. If it's `bool`, default is `false`, `int` is `0`, and any references types are `null`.

You can call it like this:

```
var listBool = new List<bool?>();
listBool.Add(true);
listBool.Add(false);
listBool.Add(null);

listBool.ElementIsDefined(0) // returns true
listBool.ElementIsDefined(1) // returns false
listBool.ElementIsDefined(2) // returns false
```

Now quick note, this is not going to be lightning fast. It can be split up to handle different types of `List<T>` objects though so you can remove or add logic based on if you needed to create a similar method for `List<int>` or `List<MyClass>` and so on, but because I defined it as using a `List<T>` this method will show up for all Lists.

Answer (score 3):

Now that you're using C# and have access to the BCL, you should use a Dictionary for this kind of thing. This allows you to efficiently add indices and check whether they're present.

For example, assuming T was `string`:

```
var s = new Dictionary<int, string>();

s[1234] = "Hello";
s[9999] = "Invalid";

var firstIndexCheck = s.ContainsKey(1234) && s[1234] != "Invalid"; // true
var secondIndexCheck = s.ContainsKey(9999) && s[9999] != "Invalid"; // false
```

Answer (score 1):

For checking correct index just check that it is less then array/list size.

```
int index = 1234;
List<T> list = new List<T>();
if (index < list.Count) {
}
```

For checking for null combine index checking and null checking:

```
index < list.Count && list[index] != null
```

(in case if you have array of reference types)